Trying to find an old scientific story / puzzle book
This question reminded me of a book I had in the early 80s. I am in the UK and the book was in English, but may have originated in the US rather than the UK.
It was a series of short stories, each with a scientific theme. The main character was a young scientist in school (I think may have been named Maxwell) and in each of the stories, he solved a puzzle by applying scientific principles. You as the reader were invited to solve the puzzle yourself and the answers were given later in the book.
I can only remember two of the stories:

Two groups of kids having a toboggan race across the school playground in the snow. One of the groups of kids is bigger / stronger and will be able to push their toboggan faster so Maxwell, who is on the other team, knows his team will lose. He asks for a head start but is denied. However, he then suggests that his team start 10m further back than the stronger team, and the stronger team don't start until his team crosses the main start line. His team wins the race and the puzzle is why? The answer explained about inertia and the stronger team had to start their toboggan from stationary at the same time and place as Maxwell's team are already moving at top speed.
All the children have drawn pictures which are pinned up on the classroom wall. When they return from break time, one of the pictures is torn and scrumpled up on the floor with a shoe print on it. Maxwell interviews all the children to find out who did it. The obvious answer appears to be that only one of the children is wearing the right kind of shoes to match the print on the paper, but this turns out to be a red herring as, when unfolded, the shoe print is broken up over multiple parts of the paper... meaning that it was trodden on after it was already scrumpled up.

